# Spring cloud config organising files in folders

Tags: java, spring, git, spring-cloud-config

I'm trying to organise a set of config files in folders within my Git repo.
I read in the [Spring Cloud Docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_quick_start) this can be done this way:

> The HTTP service has resources in the form:
>
> ```
> /{application}/{profile}[/{label}] 
>
> /{application}-{profile}.yml
>
> /{label}/{application}-{profile}.yml
>
> /{application}-{profile}.properties
>
> /{label}/{application}-{profile}.properties
> ```

So I created my config structure following the first pattern:

`app1/uat/application.yml`

But the Config service doesn't find it. It doesn't really say much about what the files inside the profile folder should look like, and everywhere I see examples of the 2nd and 4th patterns.

Does the first pattern actually work? Can anybody give an example?

Answer (score 29):

Solved, just needed to add:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/your-repo
          searchPaths: '{application}/{profile}'
```

That will do the trick

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked for me! Just one funny thing, I have a profile named dev and it just didn't work for it, I had to rename it to development and then the folder was mapped correctly...

Comment: May not be immediately obvious, but multiple searchPaths are allowed. So just using the yaml list syntax works. The functionality seems to come from `ConfigFileApplicationListener`, though I found that contrary to stated in its documentation, precedence is decided in reverse: last location in the list wins.

Comment: @Toyo, did you have to rename the profile or the folder to 'development' for it to work?

Comment: @user5163359, I am sorry it has been so long I don't remember anymore, but by reading my comment, I suspect I renamed everything to development.